# ASP.NET application times out prematurely after 15 minutes

Tags: asp.net, iis, timeout

I have an ASP.NET application running on IIS. Both the session state timeout in the web.config and the process idle timeout in the application pool settings are set to 120 minutes, but the application always times out after only 15 minutes despite these settings. Are there any other settings I should be aware of?

Comment: Can you show what configuration you have set in web.config? IIS allow session timeout is 20 mins by default. Did you set it? https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkrpR.png Did you use any reverse proxy or load balance server before IIS?

Comment: The session state is set in the web.config file as follows:
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="120"></sessionState>

Comment: Try to use StateServer not InProc. Memory may affect timeout if free memory too less.